# Cannot import a file in another file

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a file calc.py where I have methods for basic calculations.Now I crate another file (in the same directory) called test_calc.py for unittesting the methods in calc.py file.But in the test_calc.py file,when I type import calc, it says 'no such module'.If I am in the same directory,why can't I import calc?

Here is a screen shot of my project structure
[image]

This is what I get when I try to import calc into the test_calc.py file
[image]

So what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try at least, as recommended here

```
 from . import calc
```

Python 3 doesn't allow implicit relative imports.

Comment: yeah I know its just that Stackoverflow doesn't allow to accept someone'e answer until 10 minutes is gone.

Comment: @SouvikRay I always forgot about that ;)

Comment: I am stuck in a new error of the same question.Think you can answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752458/python-generates-systemerror-when-trying-to-import-a-module-into-another-module