# Python generates SystemError when trying to import a module into another module

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a file calc.py where I have methods for basic calculations.Now I create another file (in the same directory) called test_calc.py for unittesting the methods in calc.py file.But when I try to run test_calc.py either through command line using

```
python3 -m unittest test_calc.py
```

or since I have included **name** == "**main**"

```
python3 test_calc.py
```

or try to run it directly through the IDE,I get an error that says

```
from . import calc
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Below is the screenshot of my project structure

[image]

Below is the screenshot of how I import the calc.py file and it accepts the import

[image]

This is the code in test_calc.py file which unitests the methods defined in calc.py file

```
import unittest
from . import calc

class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        result = calc.add(5,2)
        self.assertEqual(result,7)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the above code, Python thows error.What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to "[Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/6309)", which suggests, amongst other alternative

```
python3 -m unittest mypackage.test_calc.py
```

Try at least to *not* have a space in your 'unittest module' folder.

See also [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/).

Comment: "Try at least to not have a space in your 'unittest module' folder." --- This solved the problem!Thanks again!

Comment: I renamed the folder to unittest_module.So instead of doing from . import calc, I did from unittest_module import calc and it worked.